# View holder Radio button with list view

Tags: java, android, xml, custom-adapter

I am trying to develop a quiz app with list view custom adapter, But when I select a radio button and scroll down I saw another radio button is automatically selected and I use view holder and I don't know how to solve this problem.

[Here is my Video.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MzjYR-bqJ_ru1N5jgI24c6fSKQeZvOL9/view?usp=sharing)

Code for my custom adapter.

**QuestionAdapter**

```
public class QuestionAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<Question> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList;

    public QuestionAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.question_listitem, questionArrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.questionArrayList = questionArrayList;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView question;
        protected RadioButton choice1;
        protected RadioButton choice2;
        protected RadioButton choice3;
        protected RadioButton choice4;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_listitem,parent,false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.question = convertView.findViewById(R.id.question);
            viewHolder.choice1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice1);
            viewHolder.choice2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice2);
            viewHolder.choice3 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice3);
            viewHolder.choice4 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.choice4);

            viewHolder.choice1.setSelected(false);
            viewHolder.choice2.setSelected(false);
            viewHolder.choice3.setSelected(false);
            viewHolder.choice4.setSelected(false);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        viewHolder.choice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice1Selected(true);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice2Selected(false);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice3Selected(false);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice4Selected(false);
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.choice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice1Selected(false);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice2Selected(true);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice3Selected(false);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice4Selected(false);
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.choice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice1Selected(false);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice2Selected(false);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice3Selected(true);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice4Selected(false);
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.choice4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice1Selected(false);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice2Selected(false);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice3Selected(false);
                questionArrayList.get(position).setChoice4Selected(true);
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.question.setText(questionArrayList.get(position).getQuestion().toString());
        viewHolder.choice1.setText(questionArrayList.get(position).getCoice1().toString());
        viewHolder.choice2.setText(questionArrayList.get(position).getCoice2().toString());
        viewHolder.choice3.setText(questionArrayList.get(position).getCoice3().toString());
        viewHolder.choice4.setText(questionArrayList.get(position).getCoice4().toString());


        viewHolder.choice1.setSelected(questionArrayList.get(position).getChoice1Selected());
        viewHolder.choice2.setSelected(questionArrayList.get(position).getChoice2Selected());
        viewHolder.choice3.setSelected(questionArrayList.get(position).getChoice3Selected());
        viewHolder.choice4.setSelected(questionArrayList.get(position).getChoice4Selected());

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Here is my xml file.

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:text="Question"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choice1"
            android:text="choice1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choice2"
            android:text="choice2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choice3"
            android:text="choice3"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/choice4"
            android:text="choice4"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you know recycler view.

Comment: Why are you not using radio groups ?

Comment: I am using radio group , You can check from the video that I gave.

Comment: so with radio group why are you setting values for all 4 radio buttons ? Radio group by default has a single selection only

Comment: You have 4 radio buttons. I don't think you are using radio group

Comment: If you are doing this code. Then you did not understand RadioGroup functionality well.

Comment: do post your xml.

Comment: save your radio button state in your list and use from list in your view holder.

Comment: with radio group you don't need to get all radio buttons.Just get the checked radio button id from radio group and find that radio button only

Answer (score 0):

I have a bunch of suggestions for you. Here we start.

- Use **[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)** instead of ListView. Already many developers faced your issue & RecyclerView came to the scene.
- Use **[RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup)** instead of managing 4 checkbox. What if you needed 10 radio buttons in future then you will manage 10 buttons? You can just hold the radio button id. Then process selected Id when submitting form.

Like

```
rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
        RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)group.findViewById(checkedId);
        boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
        if (isChecked)
        {
          your radio button is checked. you can put this radio button id in your question mode.
        }
    }
});
```

- Get item once from list then use everywhere.

Like

```
    Question q = questionArrayList.get(position); // use everywhere instead of fetching from List.
    viewHolder.choice1.setSelected(q.getChoice1Selected());
    viewHolder.choice2.setSelected(q.getChoice2Selected());
    viewHolder.choice3.setSelected(q.getChoice3Selected());
    viewHolder.choice4.setSelected(q.getChoice4Selected());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and change according to your code and take one boolean field into question pojo class..

```
public class RecyclerViewAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdpater.ItemViewHolder> {
List<Question> mQuestionList = new ArrayList<>();// hear you can pass any pojo class object.
Context mContext;
OnItemClick onItemClick;

public void setOnItemClick(OnItemClick onItemClick) {
    this.onItemClick = onItemClick;
}

public interface OnItemClick {
    void getPosition(Question data); //pass any data to shared it.
}

public RecyclerViewAdpater(List<Question> mQuestionList, Context mContext) {
    this.mQuestionList = mQuestionList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    final Question str=mQuestionList.get(position); //  here your boject
    holder.textView.setText(str.getName());
    if (str.isSelected()){
        // hear set your radio button select or unselect.
        holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.getPosition(str);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mQuestionList.size();
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
}
```

after adapter define it means adapter bind into recycler view and adapter not null then call below code..

```
        adpater.setOnItemClick(new RecyclerViewAdpater.OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void getPosition(Question data) {
            // perform any operation here.
            data.setSelected(true);
            adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

if you refer same cod for your then only take one boolean value for mange select or un select radio button.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the other radio button is selected, is because ListView would reuse itemView. In your case, if you select a radio button in first item, then you scroll to the fifth item which is originally invisible, the fifth item became visible, meanwhile the first item became invisible, so the fifth item would use the first item directly.

To solve your problem, you can modify the code near `else`.

```
else
{
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    // add below code to solve uncorrect state
    viewHolder.choice1.setSelected(false);
    viewHolder.choice2.setSelected(false);
    viewHolder.choice3.setSelected(false);
    viewHolder.choice4.setSelected(false);
}
```

Sincerely I suggest you use RecyclerView as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend to use RecyclerView. it was introduced with the Android Lollipop and it proved to be a game changer. A lot of things that we hate in the ListView were fixed or changed in the RecyclerView. It’s more efficient by default.

if you still want to use the same listview u should pass the value from activity to avoid this kind of scanerio.hope its understood.

Answer (score 0):

try using if else in your adapter like below for each radio button

```
 if(questionArrayList.get(position).getChoice1Selected())
 {  
viewHolder.choice1.setSelected(true);
  }else{  
viewHolder.choice1.setSelected(false);
 }
```